# Motorola RFS4000 - After Reset I Can't Log In

Tags: ieee-802.11

I started to use Motorola RFS4000 with wing 5.7 on board. After few weeks I had to reset test configuration.

After hard reset using reset button I don't have access to this device any more. None of standard login/passwords work. 
I'm connected by console cable, and I tried: admin/admin, admin/motorola , admin/Symbol.

Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: ¿ [have you searched "Motorola RFS4000 lost password"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Motorola+RFS4000+lost+password) ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The default username and password after a reset are **reset** and **FactoryDefault** respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter CLI first to get to the correct login prompt.  Then it should be username admin and password of superuser.